# How to remove the metadata when downloading file from SharePoint library

Tags: server

if I download a word file from Sharepoint Library and modify the content and edit the file name, all metadata fields will be auto filled in which i will it keeps bank.

How can I remove all metadata when downloading files?

Comment: not sure whether I get you right. After the download all the properties are shown in the File tab in Word / Excel... in the Advanced Properties. Normally you just click on the property you want to edit and delete it...!?

Comment: which sharepoint version are u using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Document Property Promotion and Demotion** feature is responsible for synchronization of metadata across documents and its library.

Property promotion refers to the process of extracting values from properties of a document and writing those values to corresponding columns on the list or document library where the document is stored. (Happens while Uploading)

Property Demotion refers to the process of extracting properties of a document from library and writing those values to corresponding documents metadata. (Happens While Downloading)

So, If you dont want this functionality then you need to disable `ParserEnabled` feature on your web.

**Using Powershell;**

```
$web=Get-SPweb "your site url"
$web.ParserEnabled=$false
$web.Update()
```

**Using C# SSOM:**

```
web.ParserEnabled = false;
web.Update();
```

[Source 1](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/wbaer/2014/08/29/document-property-promotion-and-demotion-overview-and-considerations/)

[Source 2](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/anavijai/how-to-enable-or-disable-document-property-promotion-in-shar/)

[Source 3](http://dotnetreads.blogspot.in/2017/01/property-promotion-and-demotion-in.html)

Answer (score 0):

Out of the Box it is not possible. You need to go to document properties and delete them manually. If you would like that automatic an custom handler for downloading documents would have to be developed.