# Remove the metadata while Re uploading file to SharePoint Online Document library

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, metadata, file-metadata

We have a requirement that the users will download excel documents from the document library and update the data in the excel documents and reupload into the SharePoint Online document library, While reuploading we don't want the metadata properties, we need to remove the metadata.
For SharePoint on-premise version, we have solutions using the CSOMor PowerShell as described in the [How to remove the metadata when downloading a file from SharePoint library](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/223636/how-to-remove-the-metadata-when-downloading-file-from-sharepoint-library).

But for SharePoint online, we don't have that option as per the [MSDN Link](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/msonline/en-US/64842efa-71e1-4842-806c-8ebed3a0c06c/parserenabled-in-sharepoint-online?forum=onlineservicessharepoint).

Is there any workaround to achieve the requirement?

Any thoughts or suggestions, please.

Answer (score 0):

This is a common problem with SharePoint due to the property promotion/demotion that affects Office and tiff files. It may result in incorrect metadata values in your SharePoint system.

I am not aware of tools with that capability at present. It is not rocket science to clear the properties embedded in Office files during downloading.

Alternatives
I am not a Power Automate expert but as far as I know it can only manipulate the SharePoint metadata and not the properties within the Office files.
Switching off property promotion/demotion is probably also not desired.
You may end up with instructing your users to manually remove the fields until the "download and clear properties" feature becomes available.

Paul